# Handling cancellation of LinkedIn app download dialog in android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn SDK in my android app, which requires the LinkedIn app to be installed in the device. When the LinkedIn app is not installed in the device, it shows a dialog asking to download the app.

So far I have not found a way to detect if the dialog has been cancelled, from the app. Digging down I've found that the dialog is shown by a LinkedIn SDK class called **AppStore** in *com.linkedin.platform.internals*

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to find out if the dialogue was canceled, but we can use our own custom implementation to check if the app is installed or not and then proceed with the login process I am doing it using the below code

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //check if the linkdin is installed or not
    if (linkedInInstalled()) {//if the linkedin is installed then proceed with login
        login_linkedin();
    } else {//else do not login ask user to download the app
        showLinkdingInstallPopup();
    }
}

private boolean linkedInInstalled() {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo("com.linkedin.android", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

if the LinkedIn app is installed then proceed with normal login process and if not then show a message to the user to install the linked in

```
private void showLinkdingInstallPopup() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("Linkedin is not installed on you device please install it to proceed with linkedin synch");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            dialogInterface.dismiss();

            try {
                Intent viewIntent =
                        new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkedin.android&hl=en"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect try after some time...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //handle the dialog cancelled logic
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no way to do this. The dialog shown is from the LinkedIn API and provides no way for the caller to detect the dialog actions.